# data relational google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, relational-database

I am currently working on Google Spreadsheet. I had a look at many different sites but did not find any source that have answered my question so far.

What I am looking for is a functionality that would enable me to connect 2 spreadsheets having one column in common (Example customer ID). It does exist on Excel, see the link below.
Does it exist on Google spreadsheet and how can I get this feature?
[Example Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-relationship-between-tables-in-Excel-fe1b6be7-1d85-4add-a629-8a3848820be3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having access to a sample Google Spreadsheet would do well, but here is a formula to get you started:

```
=arrayformula(if (NOT(ISBLANK(arrayformula(A2:A))), VLOOKUP( A2:A, Sheet1!A2:C, {2, 3, 4}, TRUE),))
```

Here is the setup:

It is assumed row 1 is a Header Row and all data starts in row 2.  Also, the common column in each is column A.  So we will use column A to connect the 2 data sets.

Sheet1 contains data from your first file.  Use this formula in cell A1:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123_FILE1", "sheet1!A1:C")
```

Here, replace the URL with the one to your first spreadsheet file.  This will show all the data in the Sheet1 tab of that file starting with Row 1 and showing all rows for columns A to C.

Sheet2 contains all the data from your second file, with the data from your first file appended to the columns after this data from the second file.  To do this, you need 2 formulas:
In cell A1, we use the same IMPORTRANGE() formula but extract the data from your second file.  In this case it will get columns A through E:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123_FILE2", "sheet1!A1:E")
```

Now in cell F2, which is the first empty column, place the ARRAYFORMULA from above:

```
=arrayformula(if (NOT(ISBLANK(arrayformula(A2:A))), VLOOKUP( A2:A, Sheet1!A2:C, {2, 3, 4}, TRUE),))
```

This will then fill in columns F, G, and H with data set 1's columns B, C, and D due to the numbers in the curly brackets {}.